# Bootstrap Dropdown menu is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble getting my dropdowns to work. I can get the navbar to show up perfectly, but when I click on "Dropdown" (either of them) it does not display the dropdown menu. I have tried looking on other posts about this, but nothing that fixed everyone's problems helped. I copied the source straight from bootstrap's website, but I can't seem to get it to work on my machine. Anyone have any ideas? I have been staring at it for an hour and can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

```
<head>
<script src="resource/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-    target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Sorry, at work when i wrote this. I edited the explanation.

Comment: Could you give us the link? @user2540528

Comment: The link to the JS file?

Comment: I just copied your code and added js/css and it works on my machine

Comment: 'I copied the source straight from bootstrap's website' @user2540528, Can you give me that link?

Comment: @Chris, i just looked in the dev tools in chrome, and the JS was throwing an error, saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/BarApplication/resource/js/jquery-1.11.0.js
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Comment: @STP38, http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: So basically your jQuery isn't loaded. check if you have it on your server (localhost).

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Maybe try with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

and see if it will work.

Comment: This did it. Any reason why the local files wouldn't work? And these js sources if I deploy this on a domain correct? Just want to make sure my app still works after I finish it and publish it. (It's my first one, so thats why I ask)

Comment: @user2540528 Probably the file is named differently then `jquery-1.11.0.js` or it is not there at all.

Comment: user2540528 You seemed to miss bootstrap.css

Comment: My problem was that i had the bootstrap.css in the right place but didn't have the bootstrap.min.js included in my bundle

Comment: I realized that the order of those code lines is also important. If you put google apis as last line of code, then it does not work.

Comment: It might help to pre-pend each of those links with "http", like "http//ajax.google.....".

Comment: I don't have enough points to downvote comments, so I'll point out here @Rickka that http without the colon will result in invalid syntax, and it's not needed anyway, because the //... syntax is valid in its own right, omitting the protocol on purpose.

Answer (score 134):

I had a bootstrap + rails project, and dropdown worked fine.
They stopped to works after an update...

This is the solution that fixed the problem, add the following to .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
});
```

Comment: Solved an issue I had with Bootstrap 3 and Rails 4.2 where the dropdown would work only the first time around, but not on second click.

Comment: Grails project w/ Spud CMS - This solved my drop-down toggle issue.

Comment: thank you SO much for this 1.  everyone is saying "add the jquery before the bootstrap".  but it was like that.  This is they only answer, after more than an hour looking, that worked!

Comment: Where did you put this to fix it? I have my navbar in applications.html.erb and placed this in applications.js.erb and it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I also had an update and after that dropdown stopped working. But this solution worked. Thanks again.

Comment: This helped me immensely. Any idea why this fix is needed?

Comment: This solution worked for me. It turned out that I had imported bootstrap on my site twice, after I imported it only once, it started working without the fix in this solution.

Comment: Or if you load dropdown dynamically after document is ready, you can have the following: ```$('body').on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function () { $(this).dropdown(); });```

Comment: I had the same issue as @harshpatel991 , I was loading bootstrap twice for some reason and after page refresh the drop-down was not working.

Comment: Worked for me, in a custom WordPress theme that was using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: that fixed it! thanks, have spent ages on this. I'm converting a .Net 4.5 MVC app to .Net 6, this is just one of the strange headaches I have run into..

Answer (score 30):

**100% working solution**

just place your Jquery link first of all js and css links

**Example Correct**

```
<script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

**Example Wrong!**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Didn't work in my case. Had to use Iwan B.'s solution.

Comment: @Nabin It works because, we have to load jquery first and then bootstrap, since bootstrap uses jquery

Comment: @toddmo It works, just check the jquery,bootstrap and css loaded correctly or not from networy tab in google crome dbugger

Comment: Noppe.
That's my order on a "init.jsp" file (loading the css's after that)


<script src="webjars/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="webjars/popper.js/2.9.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="webjars/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/5.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

Answer (score 17):

Put the jquery js link before the bootstrap js link like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Put the jquery css ...` > `Put the jquery js ...`

Comment: Your words are correct but the code blocks are the opposite of what you say.

Answer (score 10):

According to getBootstrap.com (version 4), dropdowns are built on third-party library Popper.js. So, if the dropdown menu does not work onclick but is working only on hover of the dropdown include popper.js, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css. Not including popper.js before including bootstrap bundles could be one of the reasons.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: For the version 4 this is the answer which is a big change when we are used to only include Jquery and bootstrap in our projects.

Comment: Yes, the order really matters.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. Copied the same codes from the Bootstrap page, but this is the right order they should be in.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone still facing same problem be sure to check your your **view Page source** in your browser to check whether all the jquery and bootstrap files are loaded and paths to the file are correct. Most important! make sure to use latest stable jquery file.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this while I was using ASP .NET Forms. The solution I used was deleting or commenting out jQuery and Bootstrap references from the `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">` in the master page. It seems it creates a conflict with the jQuery and Bootstrap references that you put in the `<header>`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe someone out there can benefit from this:

### Summary (a.k.a. tl;dr)

Bootstrap dropdowns stopped dropping down due to upgrade from `django-bootstrap3` version `6.2.2` to `11.0.0`.

### Background

We encountered a similar issue in a legacy `django` site which relies heavily on `bootstrap` through `django-bootstrap3`. The site had always worked fine, and continued to do so in production, but not on our local test system. There were no obvious related changes in the code, so a dependency issue was most likely.

### Symptoms

When visiting the site on the *local django test server*, it looked perfectly O.K. at first glance: style/layout using `bootstrap` as expected, including the navbar. However, all dropdown menus failed to drop down.

No errors in the browser console. All static `js` and `css` files were loaded successfully, and functionality from other packages relying on `jquery` was working as expected.

### Solution

It turned out that the `django-bootstrap3` package in our local python environment had been upgraded to the latest version, `11.0.0`, whereas the site was built using `6.2.2`.

Rolling back to `django-bootstrap3==6.2.2` solved the issue for us, although I have no idea what exactly caused it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using rails 4.0 and ran into the same problem

Here is my solution that passed test

add to Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

run

```
bundle install
```

then add to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
```

Then the dropdown should work

By the way, Chris's solution also work for me.

But I think it is less conform to the asset pipeline idea

Answer (score 1):

In my case, disabling Chrome Extensions fixed it. I removed them from Chrome one by one until I found the culprit.

Since I'm the author of the offending Chrome extension, I guess I better fix the extension!

Answer (score 1):

My bootstrap version was pointing to bootstap4-alpha,

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

changed to 4-beta

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and it started working

Answer (score 0):

*Looks like there is more to be done for Rails 4.*

1. Inside you Gemfile add.

   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0.2'

[as seen here](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass)

2. Next you need to run

   $bundle install

**This is the part no one has mentioned**

Open you config/application.rb file

3. add this right before the second to last end

   config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)

[as seen here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout) about a 20% down the page.

4. Next create a custom.css.scss file in this directory

   app/assets/stylesheets

[as seen here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout) a little further down from the above task

5. Inside that file include

   @import "bootstrap";

---

Now stop your server and restart and everything should work fine.

I tried to run bootstrap without using a gem but it didn't work for me.

Hope that helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the matter of the route of your route file. Not the bootstrap nor the JQuery file.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that href is href="#" you must remove href="#" in all  tag

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4 you need an additional library. 
If you read your browser console, Bootstrap will actually print an error message telling you that you need it for drop down to work.

```
Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js (https://popper.js.org)
```

Answer (score 0):

in angular projects we add angular-cli.json or angular.json theses lines:

```
      "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above answers and the only version who works for me is the **jquery 1.11.1**.
I tried with all the other versions **1.3.2, 1.4.4, 1.8.2, 3.3.1** and navbar dropdown doesn't work.

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you face the problem in ***Ruby on Rails***, the exhaustive solution is provided by [Bootstrap Ruby Gem readme file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/README.md).

or in short:

1. rename `application.css` to `application.scss`
2. add `@import "bootstrap";`
3. add `gem 'jquery-rails'` to `Gemfile` unless it exists.
4. add `//= require jquery3
       //= require popper
       //= require bootstrap
       //= require bootstrap-sprockets`
   to `application.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using pug with node js and encountered this issue.
The problem was my jquery version. I just googled and used cdn link to the latest Jquery version which caused the issue.
[Jquery and Popper js are dependencies of bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js).

In order to solve I used the recommended versions of these libraries mentioned [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js)

Answer (score 0):

two links to bootstrap.bundle.min caused that problem here be sure we call it only once

Answer (score 0):

That's hilarious xD

weird enough the getting started guide failed to work!!!!

this combination worked for me:

```
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    ...

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

> see a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cranky-danny-cqnpk7?file=%2Fpublic%2Findex.html%3A4%2C32-10%2C7&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00063b6kcby7mtan%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00023b6kidhnyx2j%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00033b6kxftgwwml%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00053b6km48op1gf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clscagfho00023b6kidhnyx2j%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00013b6ky5mrzgji%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscb1crl00023b6k0b8inh1x%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A4%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A32%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A10%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A7%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpublic%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00023b6kidhnyx2j%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clscb1crl00023b6k0b8inh1x%2522%257D%252C%2522clscagfho00053b6km48op1gf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00043b6k68twuzqq%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00053b6km48op1gf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00043b6k68twuzqq%2522%257D%252C%2522clscagfho00033b6kxftgwwml%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clscagfho00033b6kxftgwwml%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)