# bootstrap Dropdown non functional

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

As said in the title, the dropdown menu on my bootstrap navbar is not responding, when I click it nothing happens. I know this is a common error and for every common error there is a common fix but in this case I have tried several options I have found online such as placing the `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min"></script>` file first (as you can see below) but that does not seem to be working. I have tried several options proposed in the following link [Bootstrap Dropdown menu is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383547/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-is-not-working#) but they didn't fix the issue.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, 
maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 
'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Bob mobile</title>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bob</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-
target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)
</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
       <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
       <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" 
type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>




    <div class="app">

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for all answers, this is the first time I'm working with twitter-bootstrap.

Comment: You don't actually have a drop-down in your code snippet there.

Comment: It's a navbar, I know but on mobile it gets converted into a dropdown.

Comment: Aha. So, you actually mean the hamburger menu. Not a drop-down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason in your case:

You aren't loading the popper.js which is required for all things that pop up or drop down.

Make sure you load the following files (in that order):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so do I just add the popper.js file below the jquery?

Comment: Yes, and bootstrap.js